# Eclipse The chosen operation is not currenty available.(noclassdeffounderror)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsch, eclipse-plugin

I'm using the Jsch library in my eclipse plugin project and while running my project I'm getting the following runtime error. `java.lang.noclassdeffounderror com/jcraft/jsch/jschexception`. I included the `Jsch jar` path in `Window->Preference->ant->runtime->Global Entries` but still I'm getting the same error.My `Jsch Jar` file is in desktop(/home/user/Desktop/),Is that a problem? If it is where that file should reside? and my Jsch jar version is 0.1.51 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant has nothing to do with running plugins.

Eclipse includes a `com.jcraft.jsch` plugin. Add that to your plugin's dependencies.

Comment: Thank You,I solved this issue. Yes,As you said it has nothing to do with ant.The problem was,I have added the library dependencies in `Project properties->java build path->libraries->add external jar` but The same thing was not updated on `Manifest.MF->dependencies`.So,I added the same dependency there and it got resolved.